# Get all the values in pandas df of 1 column based on uniqueness of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
                    video_noext                                   image
0    train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264   train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 2.jpg
1    train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264   train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 4.jpg
2    train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264   train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 6.jpg
3    train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264   train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 8.jpg
4    train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264  train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 10.jpg
             ..                                ..
             ..                                 ..
234 train/Normal/Normal_Videos473_x264 train/Normal/Normal_Videos473_x264@ 1158.jpg
             ..                                ..
             ..                                ..
138963  valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264    valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264@ 294.jpg  
138964  valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264    valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264@ 295.jpg
138965  valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264   valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264@ 296.jpg
138966  valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264   valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264@ 297.jpg
138967  valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264   valid/Normal/Normal_Videos_944_x264@ 298.jpg
```

These are just videos name and corresponding image with frames. 
Basically, what I want is to get all the corresponding image for a video.
like:

```
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264
```

should get me:

```
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 2.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 4.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 6.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 8.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 10.jpg
```

and so on...

but it should be in the same order as in the dataframe.. or else it would be like:

```
 train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 1.jpg
 train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 10.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 100.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 101.jpg
train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264@ 102.jpg
```

due to pyython sorting and I dont want the images to be in that order.Its been a while since I last used pandas. So I am all confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `loc`:

```
print(df.loc[df['video_noext'].eq('train/Abnormal/Assault010_x264'), 'image'])
```